# How to make name accessible in this code

Tags: javascript

```
var hello = {
    name: "Vishal",
    speak: function(to){ 
        return function (){ 
            console.log(this.name+" says hello "+to);
        }();
    }
}
```

I call this function as -

```
hello.speak("Vinay");
```

Actual Output is

`says hello to Vinay`

Expected output is

`Vishal says hello to Vinay`

I know `hello.name` will resolve this but how to resolve it using `this` so that using `call` method or `apply` or `bind` method this could be resolved.

Comment: Why are you returning the result of another function, instead of just calling `console.log` directly within `speak`? It would work in that case. The problem is that the inner function is invoked with a different context (`this`).

Comment: @user3666112 use  hello.name instead

Comment: I just want to understand use of call and it is kind of my requirement and instead console.log you could consider another return here.

Comment: You could use `}.call(this);` instead of `}();` to invoke the IIFE, but I'm not sure why you have an IIFE to begin with.

Comment: I know hello.name will resolve this but how to resolve it using this so that using call method or apply or bind method this could be resolved.

Comment: You can also use the new arrow function syntax, which doesn't have its own `this`, and so it grabs it from the enclosing scope.

Comment: I have used IIFE so that i don't need to give a name to this function because i don't need this anywhere else.

Comment: I'm just saying that you don't need a function there at all, given that simple example anyway.

Comment: Using (this) in IIFE hasn't changed anything.

Comment: Yeah @squint I knew that way it would work just wanted to make sure use of this in very complex structure.

Comment: So are you saying that you want to make sure the original `this` is used, even if someone uses `call` or `apply`, etc, to invoke your `speak` method?

Comment: yes @squint i want that only.

Comment: In that case, either using `}.bind(this);` or having your IIFE use the new "arrow function" syntax would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What is happening in your code:**

You have binded a function with an object **hello** which in turn returns another function that outputs something. The outer function **speak** acts as a closure to the inner function.
Here javascript behaves a little differently because of the way it compiles the code. The inner function will not recognise the this variable and rather pick the global **this.name**.

To resolve the issue you will have to do this:

```
var hello = {
    name: "Vishal",
    speak: function(to){ 

   //we tell this closure that this is to be taken from function scope and no the global scope
       var self = this; 
        return function (){ 
            console.log(self.name+" says hello "+to);
        }();
    }
}

hello.speak("Vinay");
```

**Understanding use case bind**

**Bind:**

Creates copy of the function with which bind is called. You can then pass on the object or the scope which you want to be associated with the this keyword.

Example:

```
var hello = {
    name: "Vishal",
    speak: function(to){
        return function (){ 
            console.log(this.name+" says hello "+to);
        };
    }
}

var speakTo = hello.speak("Vinay");


var speakToCall = speakTo.bind(hello); //will give you the desired output.

speakToCall();
```

Now, this is not the real use case of bind, call or apply. It was just to show you how your functionality can be achieved using bind.

Real use case can be something like this:

**Use Case:**

```
When you have multiple objects like:

var a = {
    firstname: "rahul",
    lastname: "arora",
    getFullName: function(){
        return this.firstname + ' ' +  this.lastname;
    }
}

//Another object with same properties but without the function
var b = {
    firstname: "Micheal",
    lastname: "Angelo",
}

//Rather than defining that function again in the object 'b' you can use bind, call or apply to get the desired output.

console.log(a.getFullName.call(b)); // will output Micheal Angelo which is associated to b
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, this works and I understand bit of this will explore more to understand it completely.

Comment: Alternatively: `return function(){ ... }.bind(this);` to save the `.bind()` call from the consumer.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul you are big help for me to understand this thing, I was trying something wrong to work which you made clear to me. Thanks a lot Sir..

Answer (score 4):

`hello` is accessible inside itself.

```js
var hello = {
    name: "Vishal",
    speak: function(to){ 
        console.log(hello.name + " says hello " + to);
    }
}

hello.speak("Vinay");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but friend my requirement is to make it accessible using call, bind or apply method somehow and to keep this.name there.

Comment: Not sure if hello is accessible in itself is correct terminology though ... It's accessible since it is global variable

Answer (score 0):

When you do `hello.speak`, the `this` will be become the `hello` object. Hence this.name is already `Vishal`.

```
var hello = {
    name: "Vishal",
    speak: function(to){console.log(this.name + " says hello " + to)}
    }
}


hello.speak("Vinay");
```

If you really want to do it the way you asked in the question you can do this:

```
var hello = {
    name: "Vishal",
    speak: function(to){ 
        var self = this;
        return function(self){
            console.log(self.name + " says hello to " + to);
        }(self);
    }   
}
```

You can also skip passing `self` because `lexical` scoping allows you access to that.

**But picture what you are doing.** You have an `Object hello` which has a `name` and a `speak` method. `speak` already has access to `hello` when you invoke it as `hello.speak` via the `this` magic variable. So whatever you want to do can be done there.

You are again creating a `function` whose duty is to just access `hello.name` and the variable supplied as argument which can already be done by `speak` but it is simply an overhead.

To me its a bit like:

```
a = function(){(function(){console.log("Hi")})()}
```

when

```
a=function(){console.log("Hi")}
```

would suffice.

Wherever possible make the code simple, precise and to the point. Complicated codes are not better, but its actually the opposite. Again I am not sure what you are doing, however this is a general principle.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have that kind of requirement.

Comment: then can u post the complete requirement, for this simple use case it is not required.

Comment: Sir some times you can't post actual requirement due to corporate restrictions but this is the somewhat scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Since in this case the variable 'name' is constant i think you can use a direct approach and do:

```
var hello = {
name: "Vishal",
speak: function(to){ 
    return function (){ 
        console.log(hello.name+" says hello "+to);
        }();
    }
}
```

Or you can ditch the return function and do it directly using 'this'

```
var hello = {
name: "Vishal",
speak: function(to){ 
       console.log(this.name+" says hello "+to); 
    }
}
```

Hope it satisfies as your answer

Comment: Hi @shrikanth thanks for your answer but is it not possible to make it resolve using some way from call or bind or apply method? or is there something seriously wrong in understanding there real use?

Comment: A call or apply method is used to call a function i dont know how it can be helpful in this scenario :/